# Refresh List View items when an item added to the Database in Angular+Nativescript

Tags: javascript, angular, sqlite, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an app that saves items in an sqlite database and shows them in a list view.
It loads the listview with the correct data at the beginning of the app, but it doesn't refreshes the listview when I add a new item to the database.

This is the component.ts where I load the items to the observable

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    items: ObservableArray<IDataItem>;

    constructor(public _itemService: DataService) {

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.items = this._itemService.selectItems();
    }

}
```

This is the DataService:

```js
export class DataService {

    private items = new ObservableArray<IDataItem>();
    private database = new DatabaseService();
    private db: any;

    selectItems(): ObservableArray<IDataItem> {
        this.database.getdbConnection()
         .then(db => {
          db.all("SELECT * FROM items").then(rows => {
           for (let row in rows) {
            this.items.push({ id: rows[row][0], sitioWeb: rows[row][1], usuario: rows[row][2], password: rows[row][3] });
           }
           this.db = db;
          }, error => {
           console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
          });
         });
         for(let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
            Toast.makeText(""+this.items[i].id+" "+this.items[i].sitioWeb+" "+this.items[i].usuario+" "+this.items[i].password,"10")
         }
         return this.items;
       }

    getItems(): ObservableArray<IDataItem> {
        return this.items;
    }

    getItem(id: number): IDataItem {
        return this.items.filter((item) => item.id === id)[0];
    }
}
```

This is the view where the listview is located at:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Home"></Label>
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout class="page page-content" >
    <ListView [items]="items | async" class="list-group" >
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['../item', item.id]" [text]="item.sitioWeb" class="list-group-item"></Label>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

It only loads items to the list view on the init of the app, but I want to refresh it when an item is added.

Comment: Once you add a new item to the database you can call selectItems() service which will update the item list whenever new item is added.

Comment: The problem is that the add method and the listview are in different components. I edit to show the add component

Comment: call selectItems() also in ngAfterViewChecked() hook.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to either fire a new request to get the list after you add a new item, or just add it in memory on the front end if you get a success response from the save request. However, while this would work, it's not a great solution. *It wouldn't update the list when another user added an item.*

I think you should look into using [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for this. You can have a socket open listening for messages on the front end. The back end would emit a message every time something was added, even if it was added by another user. The front end listener would add that item to the list.

Here is a good tutorial using [Sock.js](https://github.com/sockjs) and [STOMP](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) to implement websockets in angular.

https://g00glen00b.be/websockets-angular/

Answer (score 0):

You can create sharer service with list of your item like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

Where currentMessage is your list of items. Bind that list to you html and in callback function on create new item call method `changeMessage` witch will be add new created item in your array.
See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-boy9pu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

And not forget subscribe on changes in your list component.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean, can you explain it more?

Comment: @JavirGallegosGarcía I create example for you see please https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-noab6c

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a new item to the database you can call `selectItems()` service which will update the item list whenever new item is added or you can call selectItems() in `ngAfterViewChecked() hook`  as it is executed every time the view of the given component has been checked by the change detection algorithm of Angular. This method executes after every subsequent execution of the ngAfterContentChecked()